# What is dangerous in an HTML textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I'm working on the profile section of my users.
They can define several things including their description ("About me") in a textarea, with a max of 400 characters.
In this description, I want to let my users use [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) icons. I also let them use JS tags (but not PHP ones). I guess this is pretty dangerous, therefore I wanted to know :

- Is letting people use JS tags dangerous ? I know I must block functions like `$.ajax` but maybe there are somethings else.
- Does a function which blocks string containing JS or PHP code exist in JS or jQuery ?
- Is letting people use HTML tags and attributes dangerous for my site ?

Thank you !

Comment: You upload nothing ? How are you going to execute the PHP ? And the JavaScript ? In any case, **don't** let people upload PHP to be executed on your server or javascript to be executed on other people browsers.

Comment: yes it's dangerous, and for obvious reasons. getting the page to crash, or redirect to something terrible would be trivial, and those would be some of the more innocent examples of what one could do.

Comment: What _"JS tags"_ are? Do you mean script sections? Of course that's terribly dangerous because they can inject arbitrary code...executed by anyone else who will see their profile. Read personal informations, perform actions and so on (they'll be free to impersonate your app). They may even simply freeze browsers (not dangerous but annoying). To block AJAX call isn't enough and you can't sandbox (reliably) their scripts. HTML tags? Well dangerous for same reason...they may even change/fake your UI and perform other actions (or inject their own scripts).

Comment: The user writes his description, then it is saved in my DB and displayed on his profile. In his description, if he writes `<script>alert("hello world")</script>`, it will work.

Comment: If you understand this then letting them to upload PHP code is obvisouly even more dangerous (because that may compromise even your own site security, what if they dump all user names and e-mails?)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti What would be an example of an unsafe HTML code in this textarea ? I don't know how dangerous it could be

Comment: @tektiv `<iframe src="www.terriblehost.com/virus.exe">:D</iframe>`

Comment: @TimothyGroote Oh .. Yeah ok I get it now ^^. Then do you know can I let them use FA and Bootstrap icons without problems ?

Comment: `<button type="button" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px" onclick="javascript:doSomethingBad()">Home</button>`. 10.000 examples, they're simply able to do whatever they wants. Think about Stack Overflow itself, how it's done and what you're allowed to in your posts...

Comment: Use an existing markup system like bbcode (doesn't have to be bbcode per se, i have no idea what is out there atm) and add functions that will let them include those icons.

Comment: You can let them use FA and Bootstrap icons but absolutely not with HTML tags. Decide your own syntax and parse it to produce HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you escape all the tags before saving the form, I think it's all good.
You can do this with the following function:

```
function escapeTags(value){
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

For eg. the following `<script>alert("hello world")</script>` will become `&lt;script&gt;alert("hello world")&lt;/script&gt;`.

---

Also, you can do this with javascript only:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/
...if you take a look at comments you'll se that there's also a function that reverse my escapeTags function

```
// Encode/decode htmlentities
    function krEncodeEntities(s){
        return $j("<div/>").text(s).html();
    }
    function krDencodeEntities(s){
        return $j("<div/>").html(s).text();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's in fact very dangerous, and should only be allowed on a very limited set of "tags" or function calls.

Several systems like [bbcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) exist to address specifically these issues. i suggest implementing one of those.

They're easier to validate, and it is fairly easy to add new features to them.

It should be less work than validating actual js and php code and figuring out whether or not it is trying to do something malicious.